# Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Quota exceeded. ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I got this error while developing a React application:

```
Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Quota exceeded.
```

Below I wrote on which line in the console this error is shown:

```
  const fetchProduct = async () => {
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "langcards-db"));
  const arr = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    arr.push({
      ...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id,
    });
  });
  setData(arr);
  setIsLoading(false);

//error in this line
}
 useEffect(() => {
    if(user){
      fetchProduct();
    }else{
      setData([])
    }
  }, []);
 useEffect(() => {
    if(user){
      fetchProduct();
    }else{
      setData([])
    }
  }, [user]);
  useEffect(() => {

      fetchProduct();
  }, [data]);
```

I checked the console of the cloud firestore, and there are 52k read, I did not have so many requests because I only study and there are no clients and users. Most likely some of my code is not working correctly

Could this be a `useЕffect`?

I made to track data changes in order to rerender quickly?

[image: console cloud firestore]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have run out of Firebase hits today please refer to quotas https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas

Comment: I already read this article, but there is no answer to my question. I don't make so many requests to the server to get this kind of error. I'm just learning and testing, so I don't know what it could be

Comment: I updated the question, maybe you can help me

Comment: still the answer that you are out of quota. you have used up more than 50k reads. if you say you don't read that much then you're probably getting a logic error

Comment: maybe I'm doing something wrong somewhere that sends so many requests to the server. could this be a useeffect with data or user dependencies?

Comment: this is an annoying error of many react users. you may have to debug the entire tree leading up to that call

Comment: okay, then tomorrow, when the quotas allow again, I'll do it. Thank you

Comment: based on the code you uploaded i have a suggestion for you: remove `useEffect(..., [data])` as this will result in a `bootloop` because in the `fetchProduct` function you are calling `setData ` (I think it's the `setter` of `data`)

Comment: Yeah, I also think that this is the problem, tomorrow I will try and write the result. Thank you for your help

Comment: Hey, I tried delete useEffect with data and everything works! Thank you!